# Custom Video Enhancement Java

Tags: java, javafx, video-processing, jmf, xuggler

I have to create a media player in java which must play all known formats of audio/video. Apart from usual tasks like play/pause/stop/rewind etc., I need to apply some enhancement to the video like histogram equalization etc. A few enhancements are from some latest whitepapers, so I dont expect any api to have support for that. I would need to implement it on my own.So I am looking for some good apis which would help me to implement these custom image manipulation techniques on a per-frame basis.

I have seen many stackoverflow questions about java video player/manipulation and they have suggested to stay away from JMF and use others like vlcj,xuggler GStreamer etc. But I am not sure whether either of them supports custom enhancement techniques. Also the last question related to the topic was answered about 2 years ago(among those I could find). Also to play the video, I need some component. I have not explored the javafx MediaView about it.

So anyone has any experience about it that can we apply custom filters/enhancement to video played via javafx? And if not, then what alternatives I have to implement?

Comment: *"I have to create a media player in java which must play all known formats of audio/video."*  That's a big ask.  There are some 'known' but obscure formats that most major players will not handle.  Last time I checked, Windows Media Player did not support MOV (and MOV format is not even obscure).

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes I understand. However any java based library you could suggest which could support playing and more importantly allow me to easily apply some framewise enhancement techniques to most known formats?

Comment: I am no expert on framewise enhancement, sorry.